# How to make an image & hover image responsive?

Tags: html, image, responsive

I have attempted to use every answer to previous similar questions and can not figure out how to make my image (with a hover image) responsive. My coding (without the responsive coding) is below. Is there something in my coding that doesn't allow my image to be responsive when I add the "max-width: 100%, height: auto" coding?

```css
.imgbox {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background: url(https://www.MYWEBSITEIMAGESOURCE.png) no-repeat;
}

.imgbox:hover {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background: url(https://www.MYWEBSITEIMAGESOURCE.png) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgbox">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to write "width: 100%" instead of a static value. The width of the image should adapt to the viewport of your browser.

Comment: I did. If I do anything other than a static value (pixels) nothing shows up on the page -- i.e. the image is gone.